# Incorrect CSV parsing when reading in BZ2 file

Tags: r, csv, read.csv, bz2

I'm trying to read in a BZ2 file from the [Reddit Politosphere](https://zenodo.org/record/5851729) dataset (specifically the "comments_2008-01.bz2" file). The dataset contains, among other things, the body of a Reddit comment.

If I read the file in using `read.csv`, it works well for the most part, except for a few lines where it incorrectly splits what should be one entry into multiple columns.

```
df <- read.csv(bzfile("comments_2008-01.bz2"), fill = T)
df[9, ]
```

What happens:

| body..deleted | body..cleaned |
| --- | --- |
| We ended it in 2004, but they stole it back. Google \\Ohio voting results, | 2004.\\ |

What I would like to happen:

| body..deleted |
| --- |
| We ended it in 2004, but they stole it back. Google \\Ohio voting results, 2004.\\ |

When I use `read_lines` to explore:

```
"{\"author\":\"nOD1S\",\"body\\":\"We ended it in 2004, but they stole it back. Google \\\"Ohio voting results, 2004.\\\"\",    ..... }"
```

What I think is happening is that in `\"Ohio voting results, 2004`, the `\"` is unintentionally telling the parser that the entry is completed, which is why the next `,` forces the rest of the text into a new column.

I can think of hacky ways to delete these rows altogether, but I don't really want to do that. Any ideas about how to get around this issue?

Comment: the bz2 file does not contain a csv file but a json formatted file

Answer (score 0):

As your data is not a csv file after "unzipping", but a json file (sadly not formatted 100% correctly). So we can use readLines and then interpret each line as JSON and convert it using the jsonlite package.

```
library("jsonlite")

data <- readLines(bzfile("comments_2008-01.bz2"))

tbl <- do.call(rbind, lapply(
  data,
  function(x) as.data.frame(fromJSON(x)))
)
```